# How to implement a break in text in html with javascript with dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

My current code is (inbetween the header and body tags, etc):

```
<script>
    var products = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Keyboard", "Javascript", "HTML"];
    products.sort();
    document.write(products);
    <br></br>
    document.write("The amount of products in the array is " + products.length);
</script>
```

However when I run this code nothing turns up on the webpage.

As stated, this is using dreamweaver, specifically dreamweaver CS5.

Can anyone tell me how to get a break between the lines displaying "document.write(products)" and the last document.write without all my code disappearing?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `<br></br>` within script? That shouldn't be there

Comment: _document.write without all my code disappearing_......that's why `document.write()` should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you shouldn't use [`document.write` unless you know exactly what you are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice), try to do something like this instead:

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
  var products = ["Printer", "Router", "Tablet", "Keyboard", "Javascript", "HTML"];
  products.sort();
  var el = document.getElementById('output');
  el.innerHTML = products.join(', ') + '<br>' 
    + "The amount of products in the array is " + products.length;
</script>
```